# Should I install Node.js & LAMP in seperate docker containers or install them side by side?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, node.js, lamp

So, I want a LAMP stack, and node.js running in the same droplet (Digital Ocean).

What's the best way of going about this?

- Install them side by side with an Ubuntu 16.04 image.
- Install them in docker containers separately

What's the best option? I'd just really like something that works ***well***.

I need PHP + MySQL, but I also need node.js

I'm just a little stuck as to how to go about this, can anyone help?